# how do you solve an equation with 3 variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

how do you solve an equation with 3 variables? any ideas? I need it for ACT. here is an example:
\begin{align*}
&x+y-3z=-10,\\
&x-y+2z=3,\\
&2x+y-z=-6.
\end{align*}

Thx guys!

Comment: If you've had "row-reduction", that is the quickest way.  Otherwise, solve any of these equations for your choice of one of the variables and substitute that into the other two.  After simplifying those two, solve one of them for your choice of a second variable and substitute _that_ into the remaining equation.  You will now have one equation with one variable, which you can solve for a value.  Insert that into the substitution equation you used, in order to get a value for the second variable.  Finally, take the two values you've found and put that into one of the three-variable equations.

Comment: Hint: Add the first to equations together to get rid of $y$. Then add the second two equations together and you now have 2 normal simultaneous equations with $x$ and $z$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is called a *linear system of equations*. For three variables, this is probably quickest done by a method called *Gaussian elimination*. Rather than describe the exact algorithm, let's look at your equations:
\begin{align*}
x+y-3z &=  -10 \\
x-y+2z &= 3 \\
2x+y-z &= -6.
\end{align*}
What we want to do is reduce this down to a simpler problem, namely by eliminating one of the variables. Notice that if we "add" the first two equations together, the $y$ terms will cancel, since they have different sign:
\begin{align*}
x+y-3z &= -10 \\
&+ \\
x-y+2z &= 3 \\
\end{align*}
is equal to
\begin{equation}
2x -z = -7.
\end{equation}
This is an equation of two variables, namely $x$ and $z$. If we can get another equation with just two variables, we can solve for $x$ and $z$ in the same way.

Notice that if we add the last two equations, the $y$ term cancels again:
\begin{align*}
x-y+2z &= 3 \\
&+ \\
2x + y -z &= -6
\end{align*}
is equal to
$$
3x+z = -3
$$
Finally, we can add these two equations of two variables which will cancel out the $z$ term:
\begin{align*}
2x-z &= -7 \\
&+ \\
3x + z &= -3
\end{align*}
is
$$
5x = -10
$$
or $x=-2$. Now, we just have two variables to solve for, $y$ and $z$ which we can find similarly.

Answer (score 3):

You can see these classical and inevitable methods [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule).

Comment: Short and sweet!

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques.  Often you can add or subtract multiples of the equations to eliminate variables.  If you add the first two equations you get $2x-z=-7$  Then if you notice the bottom one has that combination you get $-7+y=-6$  This gives you $y$.  Now subtract the second from the first, getting $2y-5z=-16$  You can plug in the known $y$, get $z$, then get $x$

Answer (score 0):

Use linear algebra techniques with matrices.

For example, given your polynomials:

$$
{x+y−3z=−10} \\
{x−y+2z=3} \\
{2x+y−z=−6} \\
$$

You set the problem up in $Ax = b$ form:

$$
{{
\left[ {\begin{array}{rrr}
 1 & 1 & -3 \\
 1 & -1 & 2 \\
 2 & 1 & -1
\end{array} } \right]
}}
{\left[ {\begin{array}{r}
 x \\
 y \\
 z
\end{array} }\right]}{=}
{\left[ {\begin{array}{r}
 -10 \\
 3 \\
 -6
\end{array} }\right]}
$$

Then solve the matrix.

You can find lessons here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c